# SQL Server - Extract text from a given string field

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best method to extract the text from the string field below?

I am trying to extract the ProjectID numbers (91, 108, 250) below but am struggling because the ProjectIDs are either 2 or 3 integers long and are within different parts of the string.

```
Row   Parameter
1     ProjectID=91&GroupID=250&ParentID=1
2     ProjectID=108&GroupID=250&ParentID=35
3     GroupID=1080&ProjectID=250&ParentID=43
4     ProjectID=250
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 version

Comment: What have you tried? SQL Server has a number of string functions which you can use.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far. This is a snippet of some of the code I was using I got myself in a bit of a muddle when it came to accounting for IDs with 2 and 3 digits `WHEN charindex('ProjectID', cast(l.Parameters as nvarchar(max)),1) = 1 AND LEN(CAST(l.Parameters as nvarchar(max))) >=13
THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(l.Parameters as nvarchar(max)), charindex('ProjectID', cast(l.Parameters as nvarchar(max)),1) + 10, 7) as VARCHAR(250))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is kind of lousy on string functionality.  Here is one method:

```
select left(v1.p, patindex('%[^0-9]%', v1.p + ' ') - 1)
from (values ('ProjectID=91&GroupID=250&ParentID=1'),
             ('ProjectID=108&GroupID=250&ParentID=35'),
             ('GroupID=1080&ProjectID=250&ParentID=43'),
             ('ProjectID=250')
     ) v(parameter) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v.parameter, 1, charindex('ProjectID=', v.parameter) + 9, ''))
     ) v1(p);
```

Or split the string and look for a match:

```
select stuff(s.value, 1, 10, '')
from (values ('ProjectID=91&GroupID=250&ParentID=1'),
             ('ProjectID=108&GroupID=250&ParentID=35'),
             ('GroupID=1080&ProjectID=250&ParentID=43'),
             ('ProjectID=250')
     ) t(parameter) cross apply
     string_split(t.parameter, '&') s
where s.value like 'ProjectId=%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62fa7b60e42ada9736323de367f58ad8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I was struggling as there seems to be many ways to deal with strings. May I ask your advise as to how this could be adapted to apply to a column, if you had 100s of rows?

Comment: @SarahChapman . . . I don't understand the comment.  In this answer, the code is generic and applied to a "table" (well, derived table) with four rows.  You just replace `t`.

Comment: Gordon, apologies. I figured that out in the end last night. The split string code worked perfectly and is really useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
substring ( @Parameter, 
            CHARINDEX('ProjectID', @Parameter) + 10,
            CHARINDEX('&', @parameter, CHARINDEX('ProjectID', @Parameter)) - 
(CHARINDEX('ProjectID', @Parameter) + 10))
from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mind explaining the `+10` part of the SQL code?

Comment: yes.10 is length of "ProjectID=" .
CHARINDEX('ProjectID', @Parameter) give start of "ProjectID=" and +10 give end of "ProjectID=" place.